# ListNavigation ActionBar not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an app which had a spinner, and decided to put a the "spinner" into an ActionBar, so I used ListNavigation from ActionBarSherlock, when i click on it, the list shows but when i click on an item nothing is happening.

Should I link the ListNavigation to the ArrayAdapter?

Thank you.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    display = ((WindowManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    findViewById(R.id.minus).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomOut();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.help).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    Log.d(tag, "onCreate");
    timer = new Timer(true);

    // spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = NoScrollArrayAdater.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.cityNames, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    mSelected = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cityValues);
    mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cityNames);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    mSelected("Selected: " + mLocations[itemPosition]);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [ActionBar: Adding Dropdown Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) documentation on the Android Developers docs.

You need to set the navigation callback using `actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks()`
and you need to implement [ActionBar.OnNavigationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnNavigationListener.html).

The method is the same for ActionBarSherlock's support library ActionBar.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure what is going on in your `NoScrollArrayAdater` or why you call `setDropDownViewResource()`, but everything works when I test your code and replace that with:

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: With the regular spinner, when i click on an item it takes me a certain City, but now it doesn't take me anywhere. nothing is happening.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `onNavigationItemSelected()`. Is that being called? If so, then there is a problem in your logic for switching to a city, in which case, you might want to start a new question for that problem.

Comment: NoScrollArrayAdater is for switching cities!